# AngularJS - Optional required element

Tags: coffeescript, angularjs

I'm attempting to use a custom directive to make a conditional required statement.  The first condition I've added is 'firstInArray' to make the element required if it's the first in array of choices (necessary for a UI where you need to pick at least one item, but you could pick indefinitely many):

```
  .directive('variableRequired', [
    ()->
      return {
        require: 'ngModel',
        link: (scope, el, attrs, ctrl)->
          vars = attrs.variableRequired.split(',')
          condition = vars[0]
          if condition is 'firstInArray'
            item = vars[1]
            arr = vars[2]
            if scope[item] == scope[arr][0]
              $(el).removeAttr('variable-required')
              $(el).attr('required', 'required')
      }       
  ])
```

When I add scope.$apply() within my directive, the app freezes up (seems like infinite recursion).

Is there a better way to approach this than a custom directive?  If not, what's wrong with my directive?

Comment: Could you add a html snippet as an example?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You may be able to use the [undocumented](https://github.com/angular/angular.js/issues/1202) **ng-required** directive, instead of your own custom directive:

```
<li ng-repeat="itemObj in items">
   <input type="text" ng-model="itemObj.text" ng-required="$first">
</li>
```

Comment: Note that ng-required is now documented :)